# Uniform Distribution Accuracy

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A data scientist is testing his predictor (based on historical data) that would make predictions about Philadelphia’s temperatures. A prediction is judged "correct" if it falls within three standard deviations from the target value.  Assume that the expected value of each prediction equals the target value.  What is the accuracy of the predictor if the distribution of measurements is uniform?

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, That was my thought exactly. This is all the information given.

Comment: Isn't this question asking: what is the probability that a random value from a continuous uniform distribution lies within three standard deviations from the mean? If so, that question can be answered.

Comment: It cannot be answered if you don't know the limits of the uniform distribution.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Respectfully disagree.

Comment: OK.  Here's the uniform distribution: $[-8000, +8000]$.  Go calculate.

Comment: @paw88789, I would be very grateful for your input on how to solve the problem!

Comment: You need the full statistical description of the uniform distribution, to start.  There are infinitely many such uniform distributions, of course... all leading to different answers.

Comment: That being said @DavidG.Stork, this is a homework problem from a 2000 level course. There has to be a solution, right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Standard deviation is $\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{12}}$ so the probability of being within so many standard deviations of the mean should be independent of the interval.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Assuming an arbitrary uniform distribution is enough, see my answer and please comment if you can find an error.

Comment: Pretty sure that the fact that they use 3SDs is actually important here. If we need to be within the interval mean - cSD, mean + cSD, it may be the case that for a uniform distribution (which is ALWAYS in the interval [a,b]), that there is some c which satisfies mean - cSD < a and mean + cSD > b

EDIT: Looks like someone already spelled this out in his answer below

Comment: Your error is that you believe that the predictor *always* gives a correct answer (i.e., within three standard deviations of the true value).  The problem never says that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I'm pretty sure that "What is the probability of getting a correct answer" is the whole question. If we define accuracy as P(correct answer), which can then be written as P(x \in [mean - 3SD, mean + 3SD]), then I'm pretty sure LoveTooNap's answer is perfectly fine, since mean = target as per the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X\sim \mathcal{U}(a,b)$. Assume $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{a+b}2$ and $\sigma^2 = Var(X)=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$ so that $\sigma=\frac{(b-a)}{2\sqrt{3}}$. First, by Chebyshev's inequality we know that $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|\leq 3\sigma)\geq \frac89$ which is close to $1$.

In fact, one can show by elementary inequality arguments that
$$\mu-3\sigma < a$$ and
$$\mu+3\sigma >b,$$
so that $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|\leq 3\sigma)=1$ since these bounds are always outside of where $X$ is distributed in $(a,b)$.

**Edit**
Here is a proof that for any $a\leq b \in \mathbb{R}$ that $\mu-3\sigma <a$ where $\mu=(a+b)/2$ and $\sigma=(b-a)/\sqrt{12}$:

Since $\sqrt{3}>1$ we have $\sqrt{3}(a-b)<(a-b)$ since $a-b\leq 0$ because $a\leq b$. Thus, by dividng by $2$, adding $(a+b)/2$ one has
$$\frac{(a+b)}2+\sqrt{3}\frac{(a-b)}2<a,$$
but this is the same as
$$\frac{(a+b)}2-\frac{3(b-a)}{\sqrt{12}}<a,$$
i.e. $\mu-3\sigma <a$, as desired.

Proving $b< \mu+3\sigma$ is similar.

Comment: Hey I finally have enough rep to vote! Excellent solution

Comment: @Bayesic:  Well, as you can see from my solution I disagree.  I think LoveTooNap29 has made a number of incorrect assumptions.  He wants clarification from the OP, but the OP already answered my point that there was insufficient information in the problem to solve it by writing:  "That was my thought exactly. *This is all the information given*."

Answer (score 2):

For those who were curious, here is the answer provided by my professor:

[image: For those who were curious, here is the answer provided by my professor:]

Comment: I really think that the "correct" solution should have gone to LoveTooNap given that he actually posted this exact explanation *and* proved that mu +/- 3sigma always covers (a,b)

Comment: Okay, I did not realize that was the case! I changed the correct answer to be his! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The blue shows the distribution of measurements of Philadelphia temperature.  We are told:  "the distribution of measurements is uniform."  (I've marked the $\pm 3 \sigma$ points in red.)

The orange shows a candidate distribution of predictions consistent with the statements in the problem:  "expected value of each prediction equals the target value."  That is *all* we are given about the predictions---not that it is uniform, or normal, or uni-modal, or anything else.

(Do you agree that the orange distribution of predictions comports to the problem statement?  *Yes* or *no*?  If *no*, state exactly where it differs.)

Now we ask what is the accuracy of such a prediction, given the stated criterion that a "hit" occurs when the prediction is within $\pm 3 \sigma$ of the target value.  Clearly for the case shown this accuracy is not $1.0$, whether or not you consider the "target" to be the mean value of the Philadelphia distribution, or a particular target value (for instance near the extremes of the blue distribution).

[image: wide uniform prediction]

Here is a more extreme case:

[image: bimodal prediction]

The orange bimodal distribution of predictions is completely consistent with the statement of the problem, including that the mean is equal to the target (if you disagree, state precisely *where* it is inconsistent)... and now the prediction accuracy is $0$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question—for any uniform distribution on an arbitrary interval $(a,b)$, the following holds: $(a,b) \subset (\mu-3\sigma,\mu+3\sigma)$. Thus $P(|X-\mu|\leq 3\sigma) \geq P(a< X\leq b)=1$. See my answer and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your error is that you believe that the predictor always gives a correct answer (i.e., within three standard deviations of the true value). The problem never says that.

Comment: I disagree—the problem assumes the predictor's measurements are uniformly distributed and that the target value is the expected value and this is all I assume. I do not assume that $X$ will always lie in $(\mu-3\sigma, \mu+3\sigma)$. It is *proved* by basic inequalities and subset relations.

Comment: You write:  "the problem assumes the predictor's measurements are uniformly distributed and that the target value is the expected value and this is all I assume".  There are infinitely many uniform distributions (of different widths) that have that property, as illustrated in my figure.  Each will have a different expected accuracy (where a "hit" is within $\pm 3\sigma$).

Comment: Take any interval $(a,b)$, the mean associated with an RV $X$ that is uniform on $(a,b)$, $\mu=(a+b)/2$ and the standard deviation $\sigma =(b-a)/\sqrt{12}$. Now compare $\mu-3\sigma$ to $a$ and $b$ to $\mu+3\sigma$? No matter what the interval, the subset relation $(a,b)\subset (\mu-3\sigma, \mu+3\sigma)$. Take your $(-8000,8000)$ example and  use any software you like to find $(\mu-3\sigma, \mu+3\sigma)=(-13856.41,13856.41)\supset (-8000,8000)$ and $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|\leq 3\sigma)=1$. I don't see relevancy of the normal distribution nor that there infinitely intervals to choose from matters.

Comment: The prediction is within three standard deviations of *the target value*--not the mean of the distribution.  Both the target values and predictions change.  You think that every prediction is within $[\mu \pm 3 \sigma]$, but that's not correct.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the question clearly states that the mean is equal to the target

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Philadelphia temperatures uniformly distributed in $(a,b)=(60,70)$. Mean is $\mu=\frac{a+b}2=65$. Standard deviation is $\sigma=\frac{(b-a)}{\sqrt{12}}=2.886751$. So $\mu-3\sigma = 56.33975<60=a.$ and of course $\mu+3\sigma=73.66025>70=b$. Can you elaborate how you computed your $\pm 3\sigma$'s since they are glaringly inside $(60,70)$?

Comment: Thanks, but irrelevant.  (See edited solution.)

Comment: I understand now but the OP never assumes a true distribution on Philadelphia's temperature nor do they permit a bimodal distribution on the predictor's measurements: "Assume that the expected value of each prediction equals the target value. What is the accuracy of the predictor if the distribution of measurements is uniform?" (If the predictor's distribution is uniform, it must be unimodal). It will be up to the OP to clarify, in which case one of us must concede, as we are working off different assumptions. Thanks for your patience, cheers!

Comment: "Measurements" [of Philadelphia temperatures] are not "predictions."  (That's the whole point.)  No reason *whatsoever* to assume the predictions are uniform, or unimodal, or whatever.  *ONLY* that their expectation is the target.  That's your error.  Oh... the OP *does* assume the Philadelphia measurements are uniform... that's what is stated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The variance of Uniform($[a,b]$) is $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$.  So the standard deviation is $\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{12}}\approx .2883(b-a)$.

Does that help?

Comment: Since E[x] = our target value, can that solve our issue with the (b-a)?

Comment: $E[X]$ will be the midpoint of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick edit here to hopefully expand on some of the other answers given. I'm going to rewrite the question a bit

What is the accuracy of the predictor if the distribution of measurements is uniform? Assume that

1. Accuracy is defined as the probability of getting a correct temperature i.e. P($x_i$ is "Correct")
2. "Correct" is defined as $x_i$ being within three standard deviations ($\sigma$) from the target value
3. $x_i \sim \text{Unif}(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are two real numbers with $b > a$
4. $E[x_i] = \mu = \text{target}$ for all $x_i$

From 1. and 2., we want $P(x_i \in [\text{target} - 3\sigma, \text{target} + 3\sigma])$. From 4., we have that $\mu = \text{target}$, so we can rewrite this as $P(x_i \in [\mu - 3\sigma, \mu + 3\sigma])$. The fact that we're using $3\sigma$ is really important here, because if we were to use $0.5\sigma$ for example, then there would not be enough information to solve this problem because the accuracy would depend on $a$ and $b$. However, the use of $3\sigma$ makes this probability equal to 1. To see why, check out LoveTooNap's excellent solution which demonstrates algebraically that $\mu - 3\sigma < a$ and $\mu + 3\sigma > b$, which means that we have a correct prediction with probability $1$.

However, if you weren't able to verify the solution algebraically, then if you have R installed on your computer, you can quickly run this piece of code, which demonstrates these inequalities numerically (at least for $a$ and $b$ within the range $(-100, 100)$).

```
# Bounds for the uniform RV
a = seq(-100,100,0.1)
b = a

# Creating matrix with all possible values of a and b in the range 0, 100
ab = expand.grid(a,b)

# Getting rid of values where b < a
ab = ab[ab[,2] > ab[,1],]

# For each combination of a and b, calculate the theoretical mean
m = apply(ab,1,mean)

# For each combination of a and b, calculate the theoretical SD
s = apply(ab,1,function(x) return(sqrt(1/12*(x[2]-x[1])^2)))

# Calculate mean - 3SD for each combination of a and b
anew = m - 3*s

# Calculate mean + 3SD for each combination of a and b
bnew = m + 3*s

# Return the probability that mean - 3SD < a AND mean + 3SD > b
sum(anew < ab[,1] & bnew > ab[,2])/nrow(ab)
```

It's equal to 1, which means that at least numerically, we've verified for all possible combinations of $a$ and $b$ that we could choose from within the interval $(-100, 100)$, that $(a,b)$ is always contained within the interval $(\mu - 3\sigma, \mu + 3\sigma)$, which is kind of a numerical demonstration of LoveTooNap's solution

Comment: Thank you for the numerical demonstration. I did this myself but am not too apt on adding R code to answers and wanted to post it quickly. I will edit to include the algebraic demonstration of the inequalities to compensate.

Comment: Your error is in thinking that the measurements are the prediction.  There is no reason *whatsoever* to make that unusual assumption.  You haven't been explicit about the nature of the predictions except to say that their mean is equal to the mean of the Philadelphia measurements.  As you can see from my answer below, there are an infinite number of such predictions consistent with the problem, leading to accuracies between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Personally I don't think it's that unusual of an assumption, since this just amounts to randomly sampling from the original distribution to make predictions, and it's probably safe to assume that the question was meant to be written in such a way that an explicit solution was intended, but I concede that these are an assumptions that are not substantiated by OP's question text